# Code-rigmarole - Hangman

Tags: discussion, new-genre

This is a new puzzle where users will work together to implement a hangman game.  Users will each post a statement of code, then wait for three other users to enter their statements OR for 10 minutes to pass and 1 other user to enter their statement, then will post another statement.  Imports do not count as statements.

Due to the nature of this competition, it will take place on Chat.  If you are interested, please join us in this chat room for the link to the code room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12239/code-rigmarole.

All parts of this challenge are open to discussion and debate.

Answer (score 2):

I am having a great deal of trouble seeing

1. How this would integrate with the way the site works.
2. How it could be reasonably voted on
3. How the rules about waiting could be enforced
4. How you would overcome edit collisions

In short, the idea may have merit on its own but it is totally unsuitable for the site.

Comment: We are doing it in the chat.  Please visit the link.

Comment: 4. By using `git`.